# Gulp - Browser-Sync

Tags: php, html, npm, wampserver

Preciso de uma ajuda!

Não estou conseguindo de forma alguma sincronizar meu browser com o browser-sync. Eu queria usar no localhost(wampserver), porem já pesquisei, já fiz diversos teste e nada. No terminal aparece que esta carregando o browser mais nada acontece.... Não posso postar o código porque não tenho, já tentei de tudo diversos códigos e não deu certo. Alguém pode me ajudar com o passo a passo para usar o browser-sync? Detalhe sem ser o localhost ate consigo fazer esse procedimento, mais no localhost não consigo de maneira nenhuma. Obs. queria usar com a extensão php. Obrigado!